# Make two csv files combined with one single zip file in PL SQL code

Tags: oracle, plsql

In my code below, it takes one csv file and zip it into one. But i need to make two csv files combine into one single zip file. Any ideas? Thanks
Below is my code:
create or replace
PACKAGE BODY                BE2010_SCHEDULE IS
PROCEDURE job_morning IS
BEGIN

```
           PROCEDURE job_msat IS
    
            rmt_dir   VARCHAR2(200) ;
            filename  VARCHAR2(200) ;
            country   VARCHAR2(20) ;
            stamp_fmt VARCHAR2(30) := 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS';
            sep       char := ';';
            sw_header char := 'N';
             tmp_nclob nclob;
             ziplob    blob;
             v_destin varchar2(100) ;
    
       
            BEGIN
    
            XLOG.LOG_info('BE2010_SCHEDULE.JOB_MSAT_IN','BE2010: 
            Starting 
           the MSAT exports');  
    
           rmt_dir:= '/ForMarsh/Drive_T';
           country := 'BE';
    

                    Select mprop_value into v_destin from 
           marsh_env_properties where mprop_name = 
          'mailto.whole_team';
```

-- This part i want to merge the two csv files  into one zip file only

```
           filename := 'OSBELER_POL.CSV';
           tmp_nclob := be2010_msat_leasing.xtr_policies (sep, 
           sw_header);
            marshsat_ftp.send_NCLOB(tmp_nclob,'', rmt_dir 
           ,filename,'UTF8');
           as_zip.add1file( ziplob, filename, smtp.translate_nclob ( 
          tmp_nclob,'UTF8' ) );
          as_zip.finish_zip( ziplob );
       
             smtp.send_mail ( v_destin, '[Cleva->MSAT] BE2010 - 
          Leasing 
       ', 
          filename, filename||'.zip' , ziplob) ;
       
           dbms_lob.freetemporary (tmp_nclob);
           ziplob := null;
       
           filename := 'OSBERCI_POL.CSV';
          tmp_nclob := be2010_msat_rci.xtr_policies (sep, sw_header);
           marshsat_ftp.send_NCLOB(tmp_nclob,'', rmt_dir 
        ,filename,'UTF8');
        as_zip.add1file( ziplob, filename, smtp.translate_nclob ( 
        tmp_nclob,'UTF8' ) );
        as_zip.finish_zip( ziplob );
        
        smtp.send_mail ( v_destin, '[Cleva->MSAT] BE2010 - RCI ', 
        filename, filename||'.zip' , ziplob) ;
```

Comment: What does this have to do with plsql. If it is a database extract you need to generate the a csv then describe that process and the table(s) involved. Voting to close for lack of database details.

Comment: as_zip seems is not an oracle supplied package, it is custom code. Not sure how you want us to answer your question with just a snippet of code and references to code that is specific to your system.

Comment: I just modify my code any help